# Install magento module without Magento Connect that adds attributes to database

Tags: magento, module

I've read a lot of related questions, but my issue falls in between the cracks of what's already been covered, so:

I am modifying a module that is only available via Magento Connect.  During setup, the module adds an attribute to the customer.

I need to add another attribute to the customer.

I've modified the code to do so, but I can't figure out how to "re-fresh" or "re-install" the module.  Obviously, I can't use Magento Connect because that only provides the un-modified code.

**What I've tried:**

1. I've cleared the Magento Cache entirely, no luck.
2. The closest (I think?) I've come is by removing the module's "successfully installed" entry in the `core_resource` table.  This seemed to re-start the installation but then it  ran into a unique constraint problem ... probably because I don't know all of the tables created by the module during the initial install.

**Questions:**

1. If a module adds a customer attribute, what are all the tables that get modified?
2. Is there another/better way to simply refresh the installation of a module that modifies the database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look in the table:

```
core_resource
```

Each module has it's own entry, and once it's been installed the install scripts will not be run a second time.

You will see an entry for the module in question, delete the row. If you aren't sure what row you are looking for you can find the value from the modules config.xml

This will cause the module to be re-installed, and re-execute the SQL install scripts.

you will need to be careful and check the install scripts etc will not do anything bad if they are re-run on the database. with a sensibly made module this will just rebuild the database etc and there will be no issues, but backup just in case.

the other method is to do what is specified above, using an update script and updating the module version number.

Comment: This is what I did yesterday.  I re-installed my copy of Magento, tried this again today, and it worked.  Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed that module previously, you need to delete its entry from "core_resource" table.

Also, if module's sql setup does not contain drop (table/attribute) code, the you need to manually delete all tables and/ or attributes, that were created prevously.

Now login to http://magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

and copy key of that extension.

Now go to http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

and paste key in text area and click on "submit query" button to download that module directly.

After downloading you can place folders and files to their respective places.

Note: Place module's xml file (app/etc/modules/[packagename_modulename].xml) after all files and folders have been placed.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

i would raise the version number from lets say 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 in config.xml.
then create an upgrade script e.g. upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php in sql folder of the module.

but dont forget you will loose updateability of the module, so better just add the customer attribute in your custom script.

you run into a constraint problem, because it trys to run the whole script again, but sql is yet imported.

cheers!